# Spring MVC and json serialization

Tags: json, rest, spring-mvc, jackson

I am developing web application with spring mvc and Data sent to client in json format.
I want to  have some views of same model object thus i can return only needed data ,not more.Jackson library   **@JsonIgnore** ,  **@JsonIgnoreProperties** not suit this .Jackson library  have also **@JsonView** and **@JsonFilter** annotations but they didnt help too.How can handle this problem.For example ,i will need possibleTarget list in some pages of UI and sometimes dont need.[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637467/jacksons-jsonview-jsonfilter-and-spring) is the same question but answer not help me

```
 @Entity
    public class Warrant implements Serializable {

          @Column
          String name;

        @JsonIgnore
        @ManyToOne
        private User owner;

        @Column
        private String value;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "warrant", targetEntity = com.endersys.lims.model.Target.class)
        private List<Target> possibleTargets;

       .....
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing application layers. Don't send entities from your persistence layer to the view. Use Transfer Objects, that way you can easily control what you show the world.

You might want to use a framework like [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) to automate data transfer between layers.

Comment: Dozer rocks! :-) Agree completely, mixing JSON serialization with ORM mapping in one place.

Comment: @Peter Perhac, I want to serialize my model object to json with needed fields and .I dont want to create java classes for only group properties .Can I do that  with annotation like this project http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/42946/1954  generate getter setter at compile time

Comment: Only way i think writing  a @view(name={proper1,proper3},name2={property4} ) annotation and generate java classes ,specified by name and fields and return this generated classes from spring controller .Is this possible.Or I have to create java classes for every view manually.

Comment: Dozer framework is usefull,But i dont want to create java class for just mapping .Can i handle this with annotations.