# AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver message converters

Tags: java, spring

I want to configure `AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver` by adding jackson message converter. The problem is that I have already configured message converters in `<mvc:message-converters>` by creating a bean, and I can't reference it in `AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver` neither use `ref` in `<mvc:message-conferters>`

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="false">
        <bean id="mappingJackson2" class="pl.styall.scylla.json.config.CustomMappingJackson2">
            <property name="objectMapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>

<bean id="outboundExceptionAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="mappingJackson2" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I could define two beans one for `<mvc:message-converters>` and `AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver`, but it is probably not the best idea. Is there other way to do this?

Comment: As an aside, in 3.1.2 and later your custom class might no longer be needed; `org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` might work as well.

Comment: The reason why I created a custom class http://stackoverflow.com/a/11961094/1137146

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported yet, but it is on the 3.2 backlog. So it might be supported in 3.2.

See [Add support for `<ref>` in addition to `<bean>` for `<mvc:message-converters>`](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9469) for the Spring feature request.