# Return Client Specific Response from the Same REST Endpoint in Spring 4

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-aop, spring-rest

I have a following REST end-point in my Spring Boot Application.

```
/employees
```

This returns following response.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "department": "IT",
    "salary": "$5000"
    ...
    //There are more here
}
```

Now, I need to have this end-point used by two different clients. But the need to know only part information from this end-point.

So for `client1`, the output would be as below:

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "firstName" : "John",
    "lastName" : "Doe"
}
```

And for the other client(`client2`), the response should be.

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "department": "IT",
    "salary": "$5000"
}
```

> How can I approach this problem is best possible way?

Client1 and Client2 would be distinguished by their authentication details. Maybe a configuration which specifies how the response entity needs to be filtered. That way, whenever I am configuring a new client, I can create a new configuration for the client and that takes care of the response filtering.

Comment: How do you recognize the client ?

Comment: How do you distinguish client1 and client2? Authorization/role? parameter in request? IP address?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like:

### Client - 1:

```
ResponseEntity<ObjectType1> result = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, ObjectType1.class);
```

### Client - 2:

```
ResponseEntity<ObjectType2> result = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, ObjectType2.class);
```

Where your custom objects should look like so

```
public class ObjectType1{
   int id;
   String firstName;
   String lastName;

   //default Constructor & getter & setters
}

public class ObjectType1{
    int id;
    String department;
    String salary;

    //default Constructor & getter & setters
}
```

In above cases, spring/ object mapper will automatically map the returned response/parameters with your required object parameters(objectType1 or objectType2)

Comment: This becomes a pretty hard-wiring of the stuff. Tomorrow my clients increase, I will have to make code modifications. I was looking for a more generic/configurable option where I don't have to create new classes. Probably some configuration files, and it takes care of that.

Answer (score 0):

you can autowire HttpServletRequest object  , in the controller class, and then use it to get client details like header or user-agent information.
Then these info can be used to check the client type and accordingly response date can be build and send.

Answer (score 0):

You should investigate json views feature of Jackson. You can use the same object but filter the fields based on views. You can find some more details at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28878488/dynamic-selection-of-jsonview-in-spring-mvc-controller)