# Spring dynamically select @JsonView with pagination

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to select the Json View applied to my data depending on an URL parameter. I am trying to implement this using `@JsonView` annotations, and I tried some solutions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28878488/dynamic-selection-of-jsonview-in-spring-mvc-controller/29103449#29103449), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28878488/dynamic-selection-of-jsonview-in-spring-mvc-controller)). The thing is that those solutions are basen on the controller action returning a `MappingJacksonValue`, but I cannot use that because I am using pagination.

My action:

```
public ResponseEntity<Page<MyEntity>> findAll(
  int viewMode,
  Pageable pageable) {
    result = service.findAll(pageable);

  // Here I would like to apply a Json View to the result set depending 
  // on the variable viewMode

  return new ResponseEntity<Page<MyEntity>>(
    /* Resultset with the selected view applied, and paginated */, 
    HttpStatus.OK
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make `@JsonView` work with pagination, you need to set the following property to `true` in `application.properties`:

```
spring.jackson.mapper.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION = true
```

This will cause the mapper to also serialize properties which are not annotated, enabling paging to work.

Comment: Thanks for your sugestion. What about dynamically select wich view to use?